# How to disable the trace shown on the runway?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I do not usually follow the route indicated by the game. In fact, it disturbs me, I can not concentrate on track with that annoying indication of braking.

Is there any way to disable the trace indicated? 
I looked at all the options and did not find a way to disable this boredom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have selected an Event, go to "Driving Options" (where you would normally "Start").

Here you have the option of disabling the Racing Line.